# Make entire DataGridView read-only

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I want to display a table from a database in Windows Forms. I want to make it read-only, so one can't create new rows or modify cells. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DataGridView has a [ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property that you can set to `true`. This will make automatically turn off the ability to add rows as well as prevent editing of cell contents. To have a DGV that is modify-only you can set AllowUserToAddRows to false

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```